# How do we set the taskbar's "rectangle area"  (width and height)?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

How do we set the taskbar's "rectangle area" ?

When the taskbar is located at the bottom of the screen, I could easily set the height of the taskbar. However I couldn't figure out how to set the width.

Or rather, how did this happen? :

[image]

When taskbar auto-hide is set to true:

[image: a]

<sup>[Expand the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4RDN.png) to see the gray line (minimized taskbar) at the bottom.</sup>

From **Taskbar and Start Menu Properties** (right click Start Menu >> Properties), we have the option to specify if the taskbar would be located at the top, bottom, left, or right of the screen. But that appears to be all there is.

[image]

Just a few quick questions:

1. How do we set the taskbar's **width** (when pinned horizontally), or height (when pinned vertically) without an external program?
2. Is there a program that is capable of setting an arbitrary width and height for the taskbar?
3. Is it even possible for a program to do that?

Comment: I was wondering if you want it to happen again :-> , just guessing it looks like a flaw in resolution parameters. "Height" is set by dragging the top border. "width" I have never seen it capable of doing that.  There certannly are programs capable of skinning and replacing the normal taskbar, even putting a second bar on a second monitor, Still i have never seen them pull this off.  If you are trying to fix it, I would try switching the display resolution to different reses, fold the bar up to the left or right and then put it back.  Did a specific program run prior to this changing?

Comment: @Psycogeek hmm I'm not sure what I did, but it was OK after I did a restart.

Comment: I've only temporarily seen this happen when I switch resolutions. . .

Answer (score 1):

> How do we set the taskbar's width and height without an external program?

You can set the height, uncheck `Lock the taskbar` and point the mouse to the edge of the taskbar, which will now turn to a double headed arrow, now click and resize! yayyy! :) NO way to adjust height.

> Is there a program that is capable of setting an arbitrary width and height for the taskbar?

NO

> Is it even possible for a program to do that?

POSSIBLY NO, Also, this is not worth anything, its like *can I invert the screen upside down*, well it not worth anything but we'd like to see that :D ! adjusting the taskbar make it look ugly though :)

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 8.1

You can just open the registry ( HKEY_CURRENT_USER / Control Panel / Desktop / WindowsMetric ), right click and 'New --> String Value'

Set the name of the new String Value as: MinWidth

Set your desired value by clicking on the 'MinWidth' string, then select 'Modify', then add in your desired value (something around 120 worked well for the wide task bar button to reduce it from the stock 160 width)

Log out of your user and back in. Done.

For Windows 7,

Go to the same registry, adjust the 'MinWidth' value to your desired width, log out and back in again.